# JDBC Driver implementation and class loading

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Not a long time ago I was implementing JDBC driver. But before jumping into work I've studied some MySQL JDBC driver sources and found out that they contain two implementations of the `java.sql.Driver` interface: [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/Driver.java) and [com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/NonRegisteringDriver.java), where `Driver` also extends `NonRegisteringDriver`.

The `Driver` class only contains a static block that calls `DriverManager.registerDriver()` to register the class:

```
static {
    try {
        java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
    } catch (SQLException E) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't register driver!");
    }
}
```

While `NonRegisteringDriver` implements all the `java.sql.Driver` interface methods.

My first thought was, that by implementing a driver this way developers of MySQL driver are following [java.sql.Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html) guidlines that state the following:

> It is strongly recommended that each Driver class should be small and standalone so that the Driver class can be loaded and queried without bringing in vast quantities of supporting code.

But if I understand Java classloading correctly, there is absolutely no point in having separate `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class, as its parent with all the realisation code will be loaded anyway before execution of the static block.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, actually without `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class present implementation of `mysql` JDBC driver will not satisfy `java.sql.Driver` agreement, which [claims](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/sql/Driver.java):

> When a Driver class is loaded, it should create an instance of 
>   itself and register it with the DriverManager. This means that a  user can load and register a driver by calling

```
Class.forName("foo.bah.Driver")}
```

`com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver` class doesn't contain this part of creating self-instance and registering it.

Why did `mysql` developers decided to distinguish implementation itself from class which essentially registers its instance? Hard to say exactly, but it could be convenient in case if they will decide to provide several implementations in same package. Then class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` will extend default one.

**UPDATE**: Essenstially things are as I described above. There are at least 3 derived classes which extend `com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver`:

- com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
- com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver
- com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringReplicationDriver

While `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is default implementation, others overrides some methods from base class. If `NonRegisteringDriver` would contain static block for creation its instance and registering it, it would be not possible to have exactly one needed `mysql` driver in memory with deriving classes.

But in general there is no strong reasons for that. For example `org.postgresql.Driver` implementation [contains](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/postgresql/postgresql/9.1-901.jdbc4/org/postgresql/Driver.java/) full implementation of `java.sql.Driver` in itself.

Comment: How is this convenient in case of several implementations? Could you please elaborate this?

Comment: This was just the guess. If developers of library will decide to add alternative implementation which uses some code from `com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver`, they can easily derive new `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver2` (for instance) extending `NonRegisteringDriver`. If `NonRegisteringDriver` would contain static block for registering it self, this will not allow to have exactly one registered and desired driver in case of usage `Driver2`.

Comment: This was one nice guess indeed. Thank you.